# Директивы препроцессора #ifdef #define и #undef

Tags: c++, препроцессор

В чем здесь проблема? Почему `n` всегда равно либо 100 и 100, либо 200 и 200, как ни крути.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifdef A
    #define N 100
#else  
    #define N 200
#endif


int main()
{
    #define A
    int n = N;
    cout << n << endl;
    #undef A
    #define B
    n = N;
    cout << n << endl;
    #undef B
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Предпроцессор - нужен не для того, что бы писать программу времени выполнения, а для того, что бы сгенерировать код(программу) времени компиляции. Например создать две сборки debug и release. Или в вашем случае два модуля, один с N=100 и второй N=200. Всё верно. Или так или так, но не две одновременно (условно).

Предпроцессор не умеет делать "процедуры и функции" процессинга в широком смысле (функции аргумента - существуют). Т.е. реальный код генерируется за один проход. Если один раз сделано `#define N 100` то N не изменит значение до тех пор пока снова не встретится `define N` или `undef N` (зачёркиваем "условно"). Другого способа повлиять - нету.

В коде все директивы выполняются последовательно. Т.е. код

```
#ifdef A
    #define N 100
#else  
    #define N 200
#endif


int main()
{
    #define A
    int n = N;
    cout << n << endl;
    #undef A
    #define B
    n = N;
    cout << n << endl;
    #undef B
    return 0;
}
```

Является "виртуальным" в реальности предпроцессор делает из него такой код

```
// N = 200
int main()
{
    // A задано, N без изменений
    int n = 200;
    cout << n << endl;
    // B задано, А не_задано, N без изменений
    n = 200;
    cout << n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Но на самом деле всё "условно", что бы ваш код работал,
вам его нужно поправить так вставив фрагмент ниже, или сохранить это фрагмент в файл например `def_A.h` c таким кодом

```
#ifdef A
    #define N 100
#else  
    #define N 200
#endif
```

Условно, потому что есть способ заставить перегенерировать директивы. Просто нужно сказать предпроцессору - хочу перезадать N вот так например

```
int main()
{
    #define A
    #include "def_A.h"
    //#ifdef A
    //    #define N 100
    //#else  
    //    #define N 200
    //#endif
    int n = N;
    cout << n << endl;
    #undef A
    #define B
    #include "def_A.h"
    //#ifdef A
    //    #define N 100
    //#else  
    //    #define N 200
    //#endif
    n = N;
    cout << n << endl;
    #undef B
    return 0;
}
```

Вставил комментраием то, что делает директива include. Приводить какой код сгенерирует предпроцессор не буду, думаю это очевидно.

И как последний штрих, допишите перед `#define N 100`, а лучше перед `#ifdef A` директиву `#undef N`. Это не обязательно, это уберет warning или hint с уведомлением что "переопределение N не совпадает с предыдущим предопределением".

Answer (score 12):

Макроопределения не меняются по ходу действия. Идет обработка препроцессором. Доходит дело до блока

```
#ifdef A
    #define N 100
#else  
    #define N 200
#endif
```

Препроцессор соображает: определено ли `A`? Нет? Отлично, так и запишем, что далее `N` меняется на `200`. И дальше, когда дело доходит до `n = N;`, это `N` заменяется на уже записанное в своих каких-то внутренних таблицах препроцессора `200` независимо от других макроопределений.

Answer (score 7):

В качестве иллюстрации к ответу от Harry. Возьмем простую программу, полностью аналог вашей, только вместо препроцессора - процессор:

```
int N;
bool b = true;
if (b)
  N = 100;
else
  N = 200;
b = false;
cout << N;
```

Что будет напечатано? По вашей логике - 200, но напечатается, естественно, 100.

Как и процессор, препроцессор С просматривает программу последовательно, вычисляя выражения по мере просмотра. Если вы изменили значение переменной, это оказывает влияние только на последующие операции.